# Unauthorized GET request for .NET Core RESTful web API

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Yesterday I coded myself a simple RESTful web API in .NET Core (solution named Vault) with a single method that gets the profile of the user depending only on the Windows user name. I now have a second solution that will call some requests to my self-hosting service previously mentioned. When I use Postman, I can retrieve the data with ease when I call a GET on my only method in Vault, but when I build the URI in Mainframe and execute, I get an Unauthorized error and it confuses me as Vault does not require specific login like username and password. I also put a breakpoint in Vault and unlike when I'm using Postman, it does not reach my code when calling via the Mainframe solution.

Here where is build my REST request and call the service (`GetProfile()`)

```
public VaultApiClient(ConfigurationManagerWrap configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;

    this.client = new RestClient(new Uri(this.configuration.GetAppSetting<string>(ConfigurationKeys.VaultApiURL)));
}

/// <summary>
/// The get profile.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="UserProfile"/>.
/// </returns>
public UserProfile GetProfile()
{
    var request = new RestRequest("profile") { Method = Method.GET};
    //request.AddParameter("profile", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

    var response = this.client.Execute(request);

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            $"Could not get the user profile ({response.StatusCode} {response.StatusDescription})");
    }

    return RestJsonSerializer.Default.Deserialize<UserProfile>(response);
}
```

Im hosting local so the base URI, aka ConfigurationKeys.VaultApiURL, is localhost5000/api/

My Mainframe controller :

```
public HomeController()
    : this(new VaultApiClient(new ConfigurationManagerWrap()))
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomeController"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vaultApiClient">
/// The vault api client.
/// </param>
public HomeController(IVaultApiClient vaultApiClient)
{
    this.vaultApiClient = vaultApiClient;
}

/// <summary>
/// The index.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="ActionResult"/>.
/// </returns>
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var profile = this.GetProfile();

    this.ViewBag.IsEdit = false;
    this.ViewBag.IsError = false;
    this.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";

    if (this.TempData.ContainsKey("IsEdit"))
    {
        this.ViewBag.IsEdit = true;
        this.TempData.Remove("IsEdit");

        if (this.TempData.ContainsKey("ErrorMessage"))
        {
            this.ViewBag.IsError = true;
            this.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = this.TempData["ErrorMessage"];
            this.TempData.Remove("ErrorMessage");
        }
    }

    return this.View("Index", profile);
}

private UserProfile GetProfile()
{
    return this.vaultApiClient.GetProfile();
}
```

And here is the vault controller method that handles the GET request in question:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/Profile")]
[Produces(typeof(UserProfile))]
public IActionResult SearchProfile()
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.currentuser.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            throw new Exception("This service does not support anonymous calls.");
        }

        var profile = Task.Run(() => this.personalizationService.GetUserProfileAsync(this.currentuser.GetCurrentWindowsIdentityName)).Result;

        var userProfile = this.persistenceToDataModelConverter.Convert(profile);
        userProfile.UserAdLogin = this.currentuser.GetCurrentWindowsIdentityName;

        return this.Ok(userProfile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.NotFound(ex);
    }
}
```

Lastly, here are a few pics of before and when the error is thrown.
[image: What the client holds]

[image: What the request holds]

[image: The error]

Comment: It seems like that you must provide credentials with the client request,

Comment: @hellowstone Adding credentials to the client request fixed the problem. If you want to post your answer i will tag it as solved :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credential information must be provided with client request in order to authenticate with the server.

Comment: To add on credential information should be sent as a body when doing a POST request.I sent it as raw data :{ "password" : "mypass"}